# Having class or function as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, function-pointers

I wasn't sure what to search for, so I'll try to explain as best as possible. In the STL, `std::set` is defined as

```
template <class Key, class Compare, class Allocator> class set;
```

From http://cplusplus.com:

**Compare**: Comparison class: A class that takes two arguments of the same type as the container elements and returns a bool. The expression comp(a,b), where comp is an object of this comparison class and a and b are elements of the container *[...]*. This can either be a class implementing a function call operator or a pointer to a function *[...]*.

I am talking about the `Compare` template parameter.

So if I were to write a template class, that has a template parameter which is a class implementing a function call operator, I'd write

```
template <class T, class Combine>
class MyClass
{
public:
    Combine func;
    MyClass()
    {
        func = Combine();
    }
    T do_it(T a, T b)
    {
        return func(a, b);
    }
};

class IntCombine
{
public:
    int operator () (int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
};

//...
MyClass<int, IntCombine> ob;
ob.do_it(4, 5);
```

Or, if I were to write it so the second template parameter is a function:

```
template <class T, T Combine(T, T)>
class MyClass
{
public:
    Combine func;
    MyClass()
    {
        func = Combine;
    }
    T do_it(T a, T b)
    {
        return func(a, b);
    }
};

int IntCombine(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

//...
MyClass<int, IntCombine> ob;
ob.do_it(4, 5);
```

However, in the STL you can use the set class either way. How is this realised? The above code works only if the second template parameter in my definition of `ob` is either a class implementing `operator ()` or a function, respectively, but I cannot write `MyClass` so that both will work.

My examples may look fairly useless. Basically I want to write a container that can combine elements, and that is as generic as the STL containers.

Answer (score 0):

> The above code works only if the second template parameter in my definition of ob is either a class implementing operator () or a function, respectively, but I cannot write MyClass so that both will work.

Yes you can:

```
template <typename F>
struct foo {
    F f;
    void call() {
        f();
    }
};

void function() {
    std::cout << "function called" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    foo<void(*)()> a = { function };
    a.call();
}
```

This is exactly following the [example of the `std::set` constructor](http://cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/set/). The important point is that if you’re using a function pointer, the template parameter is *not* that function pointer, it’s the *type* of the function pointer (here `void (*)()`). You need to store the actual function pointer separately.

Comment: It's also worth noting here that it actually is possible to pass the function pointer by template.

Comment: @DeadMG: correct, but like with the case of passing a function (not *pointer*) to a template parameter, this no longer works with the above signature, i.e. instead of `typename` we’d have to have the function pointer’s type in the template argument list.

Comment: It's perfectly legal to do `template<typename T, T t>`.

Comment: @DeadMG: yes, I know? My point was that you cannot have a template declaration `<typename T>` (above signature) and instantiate that with a function pointer.