# c++ syntax: error conversion from some_type to non-scalar_type requested

Tags: c++

Line 1 causes `error: conversion from ‘C<void()>’ to non-scalar type ‘C<void (*)()>’ requested`. I know I can write it as line 2, but how can I use the `make_class()` and assign it to a variable?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<class T> class C {
    T f;
public:
    C(T ff) : f(ff) {}
};  

template<class Ft> C<Ft> make_class(const Ft& f) 
{
    return C<Ft>(f);
}

void f()
{
    cout << "f()" << endl;
}   

int main() 
{
//  C<void(*)()> v = make_class(f);     // line 1
    C<void(*)()> v(f);                  // line 2

    return 0;
}
```

Another question is from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480547/having-class-or-function-as-template-parameter). The code is shown as follows. How to understand line 3?

```
template <typename F>
struct foo {
    F f;
    void call() {
        f();
    }
};

void function() {
    std::cout << "function called" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    foo<void(*)()> a = { function }; // line 3: { } is an array?
    a.call();
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function type and a pointer to function types are different types in the language. While in most contexts the former will decay to the latter, when used as template arguments they generate two unrelated types (different instantiations of a template yield unrelated types). 
The deduced type is *const reference to function*, not *pointer to function*. A simple workaround is dropping the `const &` from the function signature which will force the decay to a *pointer to function* (you cannot pass functions by value).

Regarding the second question, that is called *aggregate-initialization*, which is in fact the same initialization performed for arrays (arrays being a subset of aggregates).